# Highchart zoom feature is not working. It is in https://jsfiddle.net/f0n31uqx/

Tags: highcharts

JSON DATA

```
const rawData = [{"eventId":"c0nmqcdsvg8q9deq0m30","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.05,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T07:48:01.072000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T07:48:01.072000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nmimfae9qf8j0ni8ug","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.05,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T07:31:37.195000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T07:31:37.195000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nmb0cmksjn6fnmek40","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T07:15:13.736000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T07:15:13.736000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nm3ani3sc4tff6o5lg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.05,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T06:58:50.348000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T06:58:50.348000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nlrknae9qf8j0jd61g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.2,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T06:42:26.798000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T06:42:26.798000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nljuu4aaj3ehi66l70","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.15,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T06:26:03.456000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T06:26:03.456000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nlc90snrvnmlvjjrp0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T06:09:40.150000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T06:09:40.150000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nl4je4aaj3ehi3fbl0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.15,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T05:53:17.235000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T05:53:17.235000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nkstgd11ttvapiroi0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.2,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T05:36:54.196000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T05:36:54.196000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nkl7um6o2p5rlk17pg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.15,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T05:20:31.239000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T05:20:31.239000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nkdi4mksjn6fnbecvg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.25,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T05:04:08.318000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T05:04:08.318000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nk5ser46k56lsj00d0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.35,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T04:47:45.487000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T04:47:45.487000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nju6l9m1grbnmn3pf0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.3,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T04:31:22.857000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T04:31:22.857000Z"},{"eventId":"c0njmh4mksjn6fn7djmg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.35,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T04:15:00.072000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T04:15:00.072000Z"},{"eventId":"c0njerbpv76emv1io31g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.3,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T03:58:37.434000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T03:58:37.434000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nj75od11ttvap97fm0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.4,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T03:42:15.454000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T03:42:15.454000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nivg3pv76emv1g2gt0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.4,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T03:25:52.666000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T03:25:52.666000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ninqg9scdqsoh00jog","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.4,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T03:09:30.356000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T03:09:30.356000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nig50d11ttvap50q6g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.4,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T02:53:08.042000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T02:53:08.042000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ni8flolbcr7u23mffg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.5,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T02:36:45.869000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T02:36:45.869000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ni0q7i3sc4tfefc000","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.45,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T02:20:23.995000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T02:20:23.995000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nhp4mr46k56ls5aong","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.55,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T02:04:02.166000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T02:04:02.166000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nhhf2b02gddfvc6au0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.55,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T01:47:40.400000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T01:47:40.400000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nh9pgsnrvnmlusb56g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.6,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T01:31:18.726000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T01:31:18.726000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nh24ab02gddfv9dvm0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.55,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T01:14:57.091000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T01:14:57.091000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ngqeu4aaj3ehhafq50","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.65,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T00:58:35.434000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T00:58:35.434000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ngipgsnrvnmluo7otg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.6,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T00:42:13.986000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T00:42:13.986000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ngb43pv76emv114au0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.7,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T00:25:52.898000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T00:25:52.898000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ng3f5svg8q9ddk16ng","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.75,"updateTime":"2021-02-19T00:09:32.116000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-19T00:09:32.116000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nfrpvi3sc4tfe31530","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.7,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T23:53:11.261000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T23:53:11.261000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nfk4lsvg8q9ddhammg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T23:36:50.630000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T23:36:50.630000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nfcfgsnrvnmluhea40","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.75,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T23:20:30.265000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T23:20:30.265000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nf4qdsvg8q9ddei0q0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.85,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T23:04:09.819000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T23:04:09.819000Z"},{"eventId":"c0net56r46k56lrkrjs0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.75,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T22:47:48.885000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T22:47:48.885000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nelfsmksjn6fmas22g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.65,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T22:31:27.612000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T22:31:27.612000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nedqlolbcr7u1djesg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.65,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T22:15:06.439000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T22:15:06.439000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ne658snrvnmlua76t0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T21:58:45.352000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T21:58:45.352000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ndufum6o2p5rkcvib0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T21:42:23.890000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T21:42:23.890000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ndmqmm6o2p5rkbjcog","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T21:26:02.848000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T21:26:02.848000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ndf5mr46k56lrc84pg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T21:09:41.947000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T21:09:41.947000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nd7g5olbcr7u16ltkg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.9,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T20:53:20.943000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T20:53:20.943000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ncvr0snrvnmlu3afmg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.9,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T20:37:00.188000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T20:37:00.188000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nco5tolbcr7u13tuv0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T20:20:39.569000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T20:20:39.569000Z"},{"eventId":"c0ncggod11ttvao1vr50","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T20:04:19.446000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T20:04:19.446000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nc8rjpv76emv09ik1g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.9,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T19:47:58.911000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T19:47:58.911000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nc16ms4leui3od2c6g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.9,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T19:31:38.286000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T19:31:38.286000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nbphfi3sc4tfdb5tpg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T19:15:17.605000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T19:15:17.605000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nbhs09scdqsonmdp30","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.75,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T18:58:56.400000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T18:58:56.400000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nba6p0niu96p24p2e0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T18:42:35.054000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T18:42:35.054000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nb2hdolbcr7u0qa9f0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.85,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T18:26:13.835000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T18:26:13.835000Z"},{"eventId":"c0naqs6s4leui3o5q6t0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.85,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T18:09:52.888000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T18:09:52.888000Z"},{"eventId":"c0naj75olbcr7u0ngqjg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T17:53:32.020000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T17:53:32.020000Z"},{"eventId":"c0nabhosnrvnmltk37ug","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.7,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T17:37:10.986000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T17:37:10.986000Z"},{"eventId":"c0na3sdsvg8q9dch76e0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.8,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T17:20:49.740000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T17:20:49.740000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n9s77ae9qf8j6dvblg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.9,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T17:04:28.841000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T17:04:28.841000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n9ki6r46k56lqm58sg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.95,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T16:48:08.240000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T16:48:08.240000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n9csvae9qf8j6b4sog","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.95,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T16:31:47.772000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T16:31:47.772000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n957tolbcr7u0f4kq0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.95,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T16:15:27.199000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T16:15:27.199000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n8timr46k56lqhncc0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.95,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T15:59:06.487000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T15:59:06.487000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n8ltfi3sc4tfcojh00","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.85,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T15:42:45.815000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T15:42:45.815000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n8e8fi3sc4tfcn2gi0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T15:26:25.358000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T15:26:25.358000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n86jem6o2p5rjati6g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T15:10:05.164000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T15:10:05.164000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n7uue4aaj3ehnleue0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T14:53:45.280000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T14:53:45.280000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n7n9er46k56lq9v0vg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.15,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T14:37:25.432000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T14:37:25.432000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n7fk89scdqsomtc1eg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.15,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T14:21:05.624000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T14:21:05.624000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n77vgsnrvnmlt0h5lg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T14:04:46.013000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T14:04:46.013000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n70adsvg8q9dbtfmu0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.95,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T13:48:25.891000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T13:48:25.891000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n6oler46k56lq3fu4g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.7,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T13:32:05.042000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T13:32:05.042000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n6gvtolbcr7u7tpcrg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.55,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T13:15:43.313000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T13:15:43.313000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n69a6s4leui3v7bbs0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.45,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T12:59:20.800000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T12:59:20.800000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n61ker46k56lpuha3g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.3,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T12:42:57.819000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T12:42:57.819000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n5pumm6o2p5riqi370","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.25,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T12:26:34.618000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T12:26:34.618000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n5i8us4leui3v21kdg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T12:10:11.221000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T12:10:11.221000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n5aismksjn6fki583g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21.1,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T11:53:47.493000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T11:53:47.493000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n52stolbcr7u7k6gdg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T11:37:23.492000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T11:37:23.492000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n4r6ur46k56lpmqen0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":21,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T11:20:59.393000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T11:20:59.393000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n4jgvae9qf8j5bmc1g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.85,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T11:04:35.010000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T11:04:35.010000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n4bqlsvg8q9dbcht60","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.75,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T10:48:10.452000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T10:48:10.452000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n444dolbcr7u7emrpg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.7,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T10:31:45.431000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T10:31:45.431000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n3se7i3sc4tfbpemog","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.65,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T10:15:20.160000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T10:15:20.160000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n3knm4aaj3ehmp9t9g","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.55,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T09:58:54.786000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T09:58:54.786000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n3d1ab02gddfsn6shg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.55,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T09:42:29.261000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T09:42:29.261000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n35asmksjn6fk5mgmg","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.45,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T09:26:03.369000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T09:26:03.369000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n2tkvae9qf8j51p9og","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":22.35,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T09:09:39.064000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T09:09:39.064000Z"},{"eventId":"c0n2s3nlq0bla05dqod0","targetName":"projects/bv2b8auslfo000c8vh1g/devices/bjejbgfbluqg00dltv60","eventType":"temperature","data":{"temperature":{"value":20.5,"updateTime":"2021-02-18T09:06:22.336000Z"}},"timestamp":"2021-02-18T09:06:22.336000Z”}];
```

Highchart source code which is also in https://jsfiddle.net/f0n31uqx/
Zoom feature is not working.
Also rangeselector also not working

```
    function formatData(data) {
      let formattedData = [];
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        formattedData.push([
          Math.floor(Date.parse(data[i]['data']['temperature']['updateTime'])),
          data[i]['data']['temperature']['value']
        ])
      }
      return formattedData;
    }
    
    const formattedData = formatData(rawData);
    
    console.log(formattedData);
    
    
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
    
      title: {
        text: 'Temprature'
      },
    
      series: [{
        name: 'Temp',
        data: formattedData,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
```

For the record, I have checked the "include dependencies with Provided scope" option in Intellij. Also, I have excluded log4j-over-slf4j from my Dependencies so as not to cause conflicts in SLF4J, using the following line

Comment: What *following line*? I don't see any.

Comment: In chart, zoom is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/f0n31uqx/

Answer (score 0):

You have unsorted data - Highcharts error #15 in a console: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15/. You need to sort it before creating a chart.

```
formattedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/859zy6vw/